# Tweening an object's world orientation

Tags: game-engine

In my game I have a script that when I press <kbd>W</kbd> on the keyboard, the camera's rotation is set to my character's rotation. That works fine, but is there a way I can sort of "tween" the camera's rotation? Right now it's instant and doesn't look very good.

The script:

```
import GameLogic

cont = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner # Camera
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()

target = scene.objects['CharacterCollision']
up = cont.sensors['PressUp'] # Keyboard sensor

if up.positive:

     own.worldOrientation = target.worldOrientation
```

Comment: Do you mean have a sort of delay?

Comment: Well, sort of. I mean instead of the camera instantaneously changing it's orientation, to rotate a little at a time until it's orientation is that of the character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over three years since you asked, and with the BGE now dead, I will finally answer your question :-)

I understand what you mean by "tweening", but actually what is required is called lerping. [Lerp](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/linear-interpolation) means **l**inear int**erp**olation, and it is used to create a smooth transition between one value and another. One of its uses is making one object's rotation copy another object's rotation by some specified amount.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.lerp) on BGE's `lerp()`

It takes two parameters: `other` and `factor`

**Other** is the other thing to interpolate to, of like data type (in this case two object rotation matrices).

**Factor** is by how much - a float value in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

As for what to lerp, in this case it would be the [`worldOrientation`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79b/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldOrientation) of two objects.

In this simple example, let's take two cubes - one controlled by mouse movement, and the other lerping to match it. (Cube2 starts off rotated so you can immediately see it rotate to adjust)

[image]

Here's my script `lerp.py` containing my function `lerp_fn()`, being called through a Python Module Controller as `lerp.lerp_fn`:

```
import bge
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

def lerp_fn():
    target = scene.objects['Cube']
    lerper = scene.objects['Cube2']

    always = lerper.sensors["Always"] #Enable TRUE level triggering

    #'target' object also must have a Sensor conected to this Module in order to be recognized

    drag = 0.05 #How closely to copy the target rotation each tick (range 0~1)

    if always.positive:
        lerper.worldOrientation = (lerper.worldOrientation.lerp(target.worldOrientation, drag))
```

'Cube' logic:

[image: The logic of the target cube]

'Cube2' logic:

[image: The logic of the lerping cube]

[image]